# Twilio trademark registration for A2P SMS

Tags: twilio, sms

Has anyone else had problems completing the trademark registration? I want to register A2P10DLC to avoid SMS blocks and just when I put my company information I get an error, I made sure that the address is correct and coincides with my tax document, my concern is that it will not allow me to complete the registration because my company is in Mexico.

I am not sure if I am missing a step or there is a bug in the system, unfortunately I already have two support tickets with no attention from twilio.